# Colored Bootstrap Glyphicons is printed black

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I can't get colored Glyphicons to print in the color I've set. It's printed black.

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time text-success"></i>
```

I had the same problem when printing normal text but I've added **!important** in the CSS file like so:

```
.text-success {color:#688c2a !important}
```

I've also tried to add it to it's parent but with the same result. It looks good on screen. I am using **Bootstrap 3**.

CSS media is set to *all* and I've made sure of no cache with use of PHP *?t=time();* after the CSS-file.

Any ideas on how to get it to work on Glyphicons as well?

Comment: are you using a colour printer?

Comment: I knew that someone was gonna ask that. Very funny! ;)

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist. Can you put a code example up? I'd guess that you're not putting the rule in a print stylesheet.

Comment: The example is in the question. It only works for text and not glyphicons. Very frustrating.

Comment: I meant an example on jsfiddle, codepen or similar. Making a minimal test case in this way can often help you solve your problem, if you're still stuck, post the example.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll make sure to make an account on jsfiddle for my next post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've tried the suggested solutions but I couldn't get it to work.

I finally had to go to Bootstraps own `@media print` settings and remove
`color:#000 !important`

So strange that I only could get the color to print on text before removing that line. I don't know if there is a better solution out there but this is how I solved it.

Thanks for everyones input!

Answer (score 3):

Stay away from !important unless absolutely necessary. Bootstrap 3 has a media query for print styles, it's inheriting this style for glyphs:

```
@media print *, :after, :before {
    color: #000!important;
    text-shadow: none!important;
    background: 0 0!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

As you can see they are already enforcing !important. Create your own print media query that's more specific using a class name instead of just the asterisk which means everything.

```
@media print .text-success {
    color:#688c2a !important;
}
```

If it still doesn't override the style then use !important. Key is to use the print media query for something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've added your suggestion to my print sheet but it still only works for text and not glyphicons.

Comment: The :before worked for me to get a white glyphicon onto a PDF.  You can narrow it down to .glyphicon:before in the @media query

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. Actually, in the Bootstrap stylesheet you have

```
@media print {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
  }
...
}
```

**The fragment above comes from original Bootstrap CSS file, do not copy-paste this, it will not solve the problem.** This makes every symbol (including glyphicons) black when printing. The only solution I found is to remove this section from the bootstrap CSS stylesheet. After doing this, I am able to print the designed page with proper colors to a PDF file using a PDF printer from my browser.

By the way, this allows to recover all background colors and shadows that are overridden too (they are, however, recoverable using your own definitions with @media print and !important according to other posts).

An inconvenient of such a solution is that once you update your Bootstrap version, you will need to perform the same (manual) operation to keep printing fixed.

---

UPDATE: As it is proposed by Andreas in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35202733/4926545), it is not necessary to remove the whole section "@media print". It is actually enough to remove the following line from this section, if you only want to make the glyphicons right-colored:

```
color: #000 !important;
```

Comment: That's close to the solution I posted before. I only removed the line: color:#000 !important; and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If color is right on screen and wrong in prints, you probably need to find css rules for prints.

Try looking for media-query "@media print" in your stylesheets. Probably you will find the wrong color rule somewhere below it.

Comment: I've set the Bootstrap file to media="all". It's so strange that the color only gets applied to text.

Comment: If you look at the [bootstrap source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/print.less) the print styles are contained within a print media query, so I think this will override this.

Comment: Ok, so I found this line in the bootstrap file: @media print{*,*:before,*:after{background:transparent !important;color:#000 !important; ...and removed color:#000 !important; and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

the code seem to be right and working find on my end. try to clear your cache and cookies of the browser.
and if still the problem arises try to change it with jquery

```
$('.text-success').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing style-sheets can have such issues. Which browser are you using to print?

```
@media print and (color) {
   * {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
```

Try adding this code to your style-sheet. Also, please check your format and printing options in your browser before you print. hope this helps.

Edit:
If you don't mind having css in your html, you can try adding these styles in your html `<style>` tags.

Comment: @media print .text-success {
   * {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
This is not working. I had to remove color:#000 !important from Bootstraps media print.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT EVER modify Bootstraps less files, it will end up being a maintenance hell. 
Most likely your problem is that the icon will be rendered to i:before and not being the content of i element.
So have your own css to be:

```css
.text-success:before {color:#688c2a !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better overwrite the css instead of changing vendor files;

```
@media print {
  *, *:before, *:after {
    color: inherit !important;
}
```